# Why is the javascript psuedo-protocol not working?

Tags: javascript, firefox

So, I'm trying to run on random websites, to play with the javascript psuedo-protocol.

```
javascript:alert("testtesttest");
```

And it never works. I've tried 6 websites, and I have no clue what I'm doing wrong. I've tried googling with little success. I'm using the latest version of firefox, and I have javascript enabled.

Answer (score 3):

Firefox disabled it for security reasons, because people were pasting things they were told to in the address bar.

Comment: "told to [by attackers]" should be mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

but it still works, if you trigger it from your javascript code.

And in chrome code, I found many cases, a window is initialized with this kind of protocol.

For example if you visit http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp
There will be some inside windows to be opened with

```
javascript:"<html><body%20style='background:transparent'></body></html>"
```

then later on, the location.href changed to

```
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp
```

Any one knows why this kind of change happens, and why it is allowed?
Does it suggest for layer window, the location of the window can be changed to the main page?